# Comparison in Kotlin using Boolean

Tags: kotlin, compare

I'm super new to programming and everything, and currently I'm joining this course by Google. So there is one exercise that I have to compare the time I've spent on using my phone yesterday and today. Below is the code that I've written. I need the output to be `true` , `false`, `false`  but my output was `true`, `false`, `true` . I've tried to solve but it just turned worse. I need help!

```
fun main() {
    var timeSpentToday = 300
    var timeSpentYesterday = 250
    
    println(timeSpent(timeSpentToday, timeSpentYesterday))
    println()
    
    println(timeSpent(300, 300))
    println()
    
    println(timeSpent(200, 220))
    println()
}

fun timeSpent(today: Int, yesterday: Int): Boolean {
    val today = 300
    val yeseterday = 250
    return today > yesterday
}
```

I tried to change the input value and it works if I change the penultimate `println` to `println(timeSpent(200,300)` . However, it doesn't work if the number is in range of 200 to 290

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fun timeSpent(today: Int, yesterday: Int): Boolean {
    val today = 300
    val yeseterday = 250
    return today > yesterday
}
```

Well, you fully ignore the value of today that is passed into timeSpent, replacing it with a new variable that always has the value 300. You also try to do that with `yesterday`, but a typo actually means you do the right thing.  In any event, timeSpent should have two of its three lines deleted:

```
fun timeSpent(today: Int, yesterday: Int): Boolean {
    return today > yesterday
}
```

Comment: If this answer helped you, please mark it as accepted with the check box under the voting arrows.